# Raspbian Wheezy, Raspberry Pi 3 and HC05

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, serial, pi-3, bluetooth

I now this is a long shot, but some reasons I was using Raspbian wheezy on Raspberry Pi 2, and I was able to use HC05 bluetooth module with wiringpi.

Lately I had switched it to Raspberry Pi 3, yet I still want to use same sd card and same code to work with HC05. However as far as I understand, Raspberry Pi 3 had some modifications to its serial configurations, therefore I am unable to use serial port anymore. The code that used to work returns error no 14 when I try serialOpen on wiringPi.

My question is, is it in anyway possible to use an old Raspbian Wheezy version with Raspberry Pi 3, but still enable the bluetooth module? Probably I am going to be the only one having this problem since wheezy is outdated and Raspberry Pi 3 is a quite recent model, but I will appreciate if you have any ideas on what to change to enable serial port again.

Note: I have followed the basic tutorials exactly and they worked fine with Pi 2, therefore I do not have any problem with my code.

Comment: *"therefore I am unable to use serial port anymore"* -> Why?  Because it's now `ttyS0` instead of `AMA0`?  What difference does that make?  You're unlikely to get any answer to this question, and you might want to consider [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).   You're scheming on something you think will be an easy fix and closing your eyes to the fact it is probably not the best idea.  You're also guessing wiringPi will now magically work on the Pi 3 because you use an older OS, which seems unlikely.

Comment: You have not provided any information which would enable anyone to give more than a speculative opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Milliways posted, Wheezy will not support the RPi3. The latest Raspbian Wheezy dates back to May 2015, the RPi3 came out March 2016. Yes, the Raspberry Pi boards are pin compatible and have the exact same layouts, but the chips are different and require different drivers. If you are interested or curious, [here is a link](http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/images/) to previous versions of Raspbian

Answer (score 5):

Wheezy will support the Pi-3 if it's firmware is first fully updated in an older pi with:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

then remove the SD card and put it in a Pi-3 and it will boot fine.

I did exactly that and have uploaded the image here for Pi Zero and pi3 users:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/raspbian-wheezy-pi/

Comment: just to confirm, this method DOES work. the answers that claim wheezy doesn't run on the rpi3 are incorrect.

Comment: I was able to get wifi working, but not bluetooth.  At this point, you really shouldn't run Wheezy on any Pi unless you have a really good reason.

Comment: It works on Pi 3. I managed to boot this image headless with SSH enabled; I don't know if SSH was already enabled, anyway I simply put an empty `ssh` file in the boot partition.

Answer (score 0):

Wheezy DEFINITELY won't run on the Pi3.