# Xojo HTMLviewer Raspberry Pi3 WebKit

Tags: web-interface, shared-libraries

I'm developing an app for Windows and Raspberry Pi using [Xojo](http://www.xojo.com/). I'm relying on the [HTMLviewer](https://docs.xojo.com/index.php/HTMLViewer) heavily in places to render web driven content.

I have multiple Raspberry Pi 3s, reading the Xojo documentation I can see that HTMLViewers are not supported on Jessie, however I cannot run Wheezy as it will not run on the Pi 3 due to kernel support for ARMv8.

I have tried using Ubuntu Mate on the Pi and using `sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0.0`, however this does not work as Ubuntu has deprecated 1.0.

I'm looking for suggestions as to how I can get the HTMLviewer working on the Raspberry Pi 3. I'm open to any suggestions - OS versions etc. The Pi will only be used for the custom app.

Comment: Would you please link to the documentation that says HTMLViewers are not supported on Jessie?  You can definitely do `sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0.0` on Raspbian Jessie.

Comment: Yes sure. http://developer.xojo.com/raspberry-pi$htmlviewer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Run Wheezy (No, Really)

> I cannot run Wheezy as it will not run on the Pi 3 due to kernel support for ARMv8

According to [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/47841/46007), you *can* run Wheezy on the RPi3.  You just need to update Wheezy on a different, older Pi before putting the SDcard into the RPi3.

Not sure if it's the best solution though...

Comment: Thanks Hydraxan14 im borrowing a Raspberry Pi2 tomorrow to try this and see where we are at from there.